# why does my Eucalyptus gunni lost the scent?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care

I planted it last year in my garden in Sintra, Portugal ( the summers are warm, dry and ,always cloudy in the morning; the winters are cool, wet and partly cloudy. Throughout the year, the temperature typically ranges from 9 °C to 26 °C and rarely below 5 °C or above 32 °C ) Soil is sandy with 10:5:5 fertilization and watering in summer.
Maria